# how to wrap a paragraph in <div>

Tags: javascript

There is a code:

```
<blockquote>1</blockquote>   
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>2</p>
<figure>12</figure>
<pre></pre>
```

but I want it to be

```
<blockquote>1</blockquote>
<div>
   <p>1</p>
   <p>2</p>
   <p>2</p>
</div>
<figure>12</figure>
<pre></pre>
```

I do not understand how to do this by manipulating the house. Now if you could first add <div> and when the paragraph ends - add </div>. But then the events assigned to these tags will stop working

Comment: Can you use `jQuery()`? It has a `wrapAll()` method that does this easily.

Comment: Manipulating the house? Is that an auto-correct for HTML?

Comment: `manipulating the house`? Your question is absolutely not understandable. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: @Barmar maybe that's a translation of DOM 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done!)

```
    var stopElements = [...document.querySelectorAll("pre,figure,blockquote")];

    var isP = (el) => el.nodeName === "P"

    Element.prototype.insertAfter = (elem, refElem) => {
        var parent = refElem.parentNode;
        var next = refElem.nextSibling;
        if (next) {
            return parent.insertBefore(elem, next);
        } else {
            return parent.appendChild(elem);
        }
    }

    stopElements.forEach(el => {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var arrBlock = []
        console.log(el.nodeName)
        while (true) {
            var tecP = arrBlock.length ? arrBlock[arrBlock.length - 1] : el

            var p = tecP.nextElementSibling

            // console.log(tecP.nodeName, p.nodeName)

            if (p && isP(p)) { arrBlock.push(p); } else { break; }
        }
        console.log(' ', arrBlock.length)

        arrBlock.forEach(p => div.appendChild(p));

        el.parentNode.insertAfter(div, el);
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't manipulate it as HTML, just manipulate the DOM elements directly.

Create the DIV and then use `appendChild()` to move the paragraphs into it.

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
var pars = document.querySelectorAll("p");
pars.forEach(p => div.appendChild(p));
var figure = document.querySelector("figure");
figure.parentNode.insertBefore(div, figure);
```

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>1</blockquote>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>2</p>
<figure>12</figure>
<pre></pre>
```

If you use jQuery you could just write:

```
$("p").wrapAll("<div>");
```

Comment: If it was all so simple:
    <blockquote>1</blockquote>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <figure>12</figure>
    <pre></pre>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>2</p>
It is necessary
<blockquote>1</blockquote>
<div>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>2</p>
</div>
<figure>12</figure>
<pre></pre>
<div>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>2</p>
</div>

Comment: The same general idea can be used. You'll need to use some extra checks so you only process the `<p>` that are adjacent to each other in the loop.